# Does Ramban say anything about eating and nutrition?

Tags: talmud-gemara, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, health-safety-shmira, ramban, nutrition

BH

Does Ramban say anything about nutrition and health? Heard he was a doctor, what to eat or not?

Comment: You may be confusing him with the Rambam (Maimonides), who was a doctor and wrote pretty extensively on what to eat, and other healthy practices

Comment: @Loani I believe the Ramban was a doctor too, e.g. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/111857/jewish/Ramban.htm